# Disable Auto-hide button on dockpanel-suite docked form

Tags: c#, button, dockpanel-suite

So, I am am able to disable the Close button on a docked form on DockPanel-Suite and I am wondering if it would be possible to disable the Auto-Hide button as well. Basically, I am trying to avoid any user to make changes to the layout of the forms on the dock panel. I am able to disable to the close button by this code.

```
CloseButton = false;
CloseButtonVisible = false;
```

Is there a similar property that can allow me to disable Auto-Hide button?

Answer (score 1):

If you check pull request #428 at GitHub repo, you can see a proposed commit.

However, my personal opinion is that supporting such magic switches is too much for a project like this. People who don't want certain elements should derive a new theme from existing ones, and manually removing them.